# Finding the largest possible value for the number of elements

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $S$ is a subset  from the set {$1,2,3,...,20$} such that the sum of any two elements is not divisible by $5$.How to find the largest possible value for the number of elements for $S$

Comment: What are your thoughts? In particular (but not limited to): How large an $S$ can you find experimentally? It may be easier to prove that your attempt is maximal than to derive the size of a maximal set from first principles. I can get 9 elements and have a kind of handwavy argument that this is maximal, but please show some work first. Do you know modular arithmetic?

Comment: Look at the classes of elements modulo 5. If an element from one of the classes is present, see which elements cannot be added to the set because of that element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we choose at least one number of the form $5a+1,$ we can not choose any number of the form $5b+4$ and vice versa where $a,b$ are non-negative integers.

If we choose at least one number of the form $5c+2$ we can not choose any number of the form $5d+3$  and vice versa where $c,d$ are non-negative integers.

Clearly, we can choose at most one number of the form $5e$ as $5\mid(5e_1+5e_2)$

Observe that $5\not\mid(5a_1+1+5a_2+1),5\not\mid(5a_1+1+5b_1+2),5\not\mid(5b_1+2+5b_2+2)$ where $a_i,b_i$ are non-negative integers.

As $0<5a+1\le 20\implies 0\le a\le3,$
$0<5b+4\le20\implies 0\le b\le3$ 
and $0<5e\le 20\implies 1\le e\le 4,$

we can at most choose $4+4+1=9$ elements